# Fedora: execute command on right click of mouse

Tags: linux, fedora

I need to execute quite often a pdf split option on a file such as:

```
pdfseparate largefile.pdf part-%d.pdf
```

Is there a way to execute such a command on a selected file by right-clicking on it? I'm running a Fedora 22
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using a standard **Fedora** installation with **Gnome 3**.

Install **nautilus-actions** first:

```
sudo yum install nautilus-actions
```

Then, open it and configure an entry with the following configuration:

[image]

Notice that i wrote a double **%** symbol, because it would be otherwise matched and translated into the current directory.

I **also** advice you to **disable** the option *Create a main menu for Nautilus Actions* in the *Preferences* of the application.

---

You should not need to restart **Nautilus** for the changes to take place, but if needed use:

```
sudo pkill -9 nautilus
```

Although it's definitively **better** to just **logout/login**.